# aiogram как блокировать выполнение handler если нет в белом списке

Tags: python, aiogram, middleware, handlers

Реализовал функцию которая проверяет id пользователя с списком разрешенных id,
эту функцию я вставляю в каждый handler:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="ping")
async def mess(message):
    if read_config.watch_id(message.from_user.id):
        get_message_bot = message.text.strip()
        mes = get_message_bot.split("/ping ")
        try:
            ip = mes[1]
            ping_ip = ping(ip, count=5)
        except IndexError:
            ping_ip = "Ошибка ввода адреса"
        except RuntimeError as e:
            e1 = e.args[0].split("\"")
            if e1[0] == "Cannot resolve address ":
                 ping_ip = e1[0]
        await bot_token.send_message(message.chat.id, ping_ip, parse_mode='html')
    else:
        await message.answer(f"Ваш ID: {message.from_user.id} Вам доступ запрещен")
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем, как можно через middleware отменять выполнение  handler если нет в белом списке пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Эту проблему понял как решить двумя способами:

1. Создать отдельный декоратор:

   ```
   def access_enabled_id(func) -> str | bool:

   async def wrapper(message: types.Message):
       if read_config.watch_id(message.from_user.id):
           await func(message)
       else:
           await message.reply("Вашего ID нету в разрешенном списке")

   return wrapper
   ```

Перед каждым хендлером поставить @access_enabled_id
(не забудъте импортировать декоратор в в файл с хендлерами)
Здесь я с помощью функции вытаскиваю список  моих id  из файла и проверяю
того кто написал сообщение есть ли в этом списке или нет.

2. С помощью midleware:

   ```
    from aiogram import types
    from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware

    class CheckOnCommandMessage(BaseMiddleware):

       def __init__(self):
           BaseMiddleware.__init__(self)


        async def on_post_process_message(self, message: types.Message, result, data: dict):
    ### До обработки считываю сообщения
           --- Cюда напишите функцию для проверки---
   ```

испортируйте этот клас в основное тело бота и зарегестрируйте его
dp.middleware.setup(CheckOnCommandMessage())

С декоратором я реализовал у себя а через мидлваре еще не добрался, возможно скоро сделаю

Вот здесь можно посмотреть инфу
https://victor-komlev.ru/klass-dispatcher-frejmvorka-aiogram/